# How to run nmap from inside a chroot?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, chroot, nmap

While I am trying to run `nmap` with privilege this message is showing:

```
nmap: netutil.cc:3285: int route_dst_netlink(const sockaddr_storage*, route_nfo*, const char*, const sockaddr_storage*): Assertion `p != NULL' failed.
Aborted
```

What is the meaning of this output and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is this just a chroot, or a container that also limits privileges? Is `/proc` mounted in the chroot?

Comment: How did you created a your `chroot` and what does `ldd $(wich nmap)` return ?

Comment: As @decarpy says, the question needs to define what it is calling chroot

Answer (score -1):

It means that in the source file `netutil.cc` at line 3285 a fatal program coding error occurred.

I would expect it's because you're missing some of the necessary environment in your `chroot` for the command to run correctly.

Comment: That's unhelpful: what environment? AFAIK `nmap` only needs appropriate privileges and `/proc`.

Comment: @Gilles there's no information in the question to draw any further conclusions. It's tagged with [tag:Kali] so I figured the OP was comfortable setting up the chroot, and just needed a perspective on why this message might have appeared.